# Break All and Stop Debugging are in a wrong position in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have an odd issue. Both Break All and Stop Debugging are in the left corner of Visual Studio 2017 and they should be around Continue.

Is there a way I can return them to the default position? It is really inconvenient.

[image]

Comment: I think this issue is related to your custom control layout. So you can reset your layout to the default. `Tools`-->`Customize`-->`Commands`--> remember choosing `Standard`  on `Toolbar` and click `Reset All`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. I will try this later today at home, as I am now at the office.

Comment: I have followed the suggestions but none of those changed the positions of the icons.   After playing with it I found out It was a simple drag and drop where I can move the buttons to my liking.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me and for chasing me. I completely forgot about that. I got an email every time I get a comment. An answer with a screenshot has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are moved you can just click on this and it is drag and drop:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

> I have an odd issue. Both Break All and Stop Debugging are in the left
>   corner of Visual Studio 2017 and they should be around Continue. Is
>   there a way I can return them to the default position? It is really
>   inconvenient.

I think this issue is more related to your custom control layout. And if you want the original control layout, you can revert the Settings to the default.

**1)** `Tools`-->`Customize`-->`Commands`--> remember choosing `Standard` on  **Toolbar** and click `Reset All`.

[image]

**Besides** this, also choose **Debug** on **Toolbar** and click **Reset All**.

**2)** If this does not work, please reset all all settings by `Tools`-->`Import and Export Settings`-->`Reset all settings`.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this at home when I come back from work.

Comment: Thanks. If you have any concern about this, please feel free to let us know.